# Changing key entry in Mifare SAM

Tags: security, mifare

While doing the changekeyentry for changing key entry in Mifare SAM I am getting the below error, please let me know how to fix this.

**conditions of use not satisfied (host authentication with keynocek required)**

The error code is **69h 85h**

Answer (score 2):

To proceed a SAM_ChangeKeyEntry you have to execute a AuthenticateHost before with KeyEntry Number and KeyEntry Version who have the right to change.

If you forget who have the right to proceed a ChangeKeyEntry on your KeyEntry. Make a GetKeyEntry and in the result you will have the KeyNoCEK and KeyVCEK.

This library implement the SAM AV1 command if you want to look or to configure your SAM.
https://github.com/islog/liblogicalaccess
and wiki about SAM:
http://liblogicalaccess.islog.com/wiki/doku.php/sam-feature